# Google App Engine keeps creating 4 instances when I want it to limit to 1

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, parse-server

My Parse App running on google app engine is configured in its app.yaml to use a minimum and maximum of 1 instance in the flexible environment, yet I keep seeing it create 4 instances. Because of this, I have disabled billing on the account, because the costs keep growing even though I want to it have a maximum of just 1 instance.

I would like to know why it is doing this and how I could stop it from happening. Does app.yaml not work in the flexible environment?

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
api_version: 1

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  cool_down_period_sec: 120 # default value
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5

resources:
  cpu: .2
  memory_gb: 0.6
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

This is for a node.js app btw (Parse).

Edit: I also tried manual scaling and setting the number of instances to 1 for that. It didn't make much of a difference, there are 3 instances running instead of 4. Sometimes it goes back to 4.

Comment: This is possibly related to an issue with the instance count displayed in the console. Are you seeing the extra instances on the graph, or do you have 4 physical instances on the 'Instances' page? I'd advise filing a report on the [googleappengine issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Comment: I see 4 physical instances, all of which are on different versions of the app. I can delete them but then they are just recreated. Honestly I am amazed that this appears to be not happening to everyone - I never had this occur before the flex beta.

Comment: I changed app.yaml to now have `vm: true` instead of `env: flex` to revert back to the flexible environment alpha and it works fine now...definitely a beta issue.

Comment: Okay, I switched back to `env: flex` and I see now that I just need to delete other versions of the app. Problem solved! :D

Comment: Glad to hear you discovered the issue. Yes, App Engine flex enforces a [minimum of 1 instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling), so you need to delete the extra versions in order to remove them.

Comment: Also, consider posting your solution as a self-answer to close this question and to help other readers who come across it.

Comment: Done! I am curious: Is there a way to replace the current version of the app on google app engine without service outage?

Comment: Great question! You should set 'gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false' to prevent new versions from becoming the new default, then always deploy to a new version, and then [migrate traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/migrating-traffic) to the new version.

Comment: 'promote_by_default false' really should be the default setting, because it allows for proper integration of new versions, but so far it remains enabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to delete/stop older versions of the app that existed on google app engine. Each one actively uses a minimum of one instance if not stopped.